# Hausdorff Measure- Lower semi-continuity

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

By definition , when we are given a set $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ , 
$$ H_\delta^{n-1}  (\partial A ) = \inf \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} [\operatorname{diam}(U_j)] ^{n-1}  \mid  \partial A \subseteq \cup U_j , \operatorname{diam}U_j \leq \delta \right\} ,$$ 
$$ H^{n-1} (\partial A ) = \lim_{\delta \to 0 } H_\delta^{n-1}  (\partial A ).$$

How can I prove that when I have $ \{A_i \},A $ which are open with smooth boundaries in $\mathbb{R}^n $ , such that $\operatorname{Leb}(A_i \Delta A ) \to 0 $ , then $ H^{n-1} ( \partial A) \leq \liminf_{ i \to \infty}  H^{n-1} (\partial A_i )$ .

Thanks in advance !

p.s.- $\alpha_{n-1}$ is the volume of the $n-1$ dimensional unit ball

Comment: Why do you think it's true and what are your thoughts so far? Roughly speaking, my thoughts are this: Consider only a bounded portion of $\partial A$. Note that you can take the sets in the definition of Hausdorff measure to be open. Then I would take a covering $U_j$ of $\partial A$ by open sets and using the fact that $|A_i\Delta A| \to 0$, try to show that for sufficiently large $i$, $U_j\cap A$ is a covering of $A_i$.

Comment: Actually I think I found it on google when I was trying to find properties of the Hausdorff Measure...
I have tried proving it using the way you suggested, but without any success.

Have you got any other ideas that might help?

Answer (score 2):

For sets with smooth boundary the Hausdorff measure of the boundary agrees with their *perimeter*. The perimeter can be defined in at least three different but equivalent ways, two of which you will find on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caccioppoli_set). But I will use the third, known as Miranda's definition: the perimeter of set $A$ is the infimum of $\liminf \|\nabla g_n\|_{L^1}$ taken over all sequences of smooth functions $g_n$ which converge to $\chi_A$ in the $L^1$ norm.

Your assumption says that the characteristic functions of $A_i$ converge to the characteristic function of $A$ in the $L^1$ norm. Take the appropriate sequences $g_{n,i}\to \chi_{A_i}$, and the diagonal sequence $g_{n,n}$ will give the desired inequality.

If this is too terse, here is a recent [PhD thesis](http://etd.ohiolink.edu/view.cgi?acc_num=ucin1211551579) in this area. Or Google again for "perimeter" and 'bounded variation".

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll try to go over it on the weekend and complete the details myself. I hope I'll understand everything ! Thanks again !