# Total perimeter of rectangeles covering the boundary of a Jordan-measurable set in in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

A Jordan-measurable set is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose boundary can be covered with a collection of rectangles whose total volume is arbitrarily small. Since the boundary is closed, and in in this case bounded, the collection can be taken to be finite.

**Question:** What be said about the total *perimeter* of these rectangles?

I'm guessing not very much, because the volume decreases to zero much faster than the perimeter.

Comment: If you take the unit disk, you can achieve a perimeter of $\approx 16$. With wilder shapes such as $\{\frac1n|n\in\mathbb N\}\times [0,1]$, the perimeter will grow to infinity as you try to decrease the area.

Answer (score 1):

By taking the union of the set $E$ with the rectangles covering its boundary, you get a set $E_n$ with piecewise smooth boundary. As the total area of rectangles goes to zero, we have $\chi_{E_n}\to \chi_E$ in $L^1$ norm. The perimeter is [lower semicontinuous under such convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169386/).

Thus, if the total perimeter of rectangles can be kept bounded, then $E$ is a set of finite perimeter, also known as a [Caccioppoli set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caccioppoli_set). I think the converse is true as well, due to the fact a domain of finite perimeter can be approximated in measure by polygons with uniformly bounded perimeter (see [On the rectifiability of domains with finite perimeter](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASNSP_1976_4_3_2_177_0) by Caffarelli and  Rivière, and references there). But I'd rather not work on a proof of this.